# how i can add list of List<string> to ListView with multiple columns

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class that contain a List of another class, and that class contains a list of string, for example:

```
class A {
  public list<B> temp;
}
class B {
  public list<string> st;
}
```

I want to add an of `list<B>` in class A to one column of a `ListView`.

i have several list of string in one class
i want to add each of lists to one clumn in listview
my listview have several clumn

Comment: Could you give an example how the output would like, to me it looks like you want to display a whole List<string> in a single column.
Or do you want each string in the list to be displayed in a separate column?

Comment: How could you asure that all the lists contain the same amount of columns?
And would you want to name the columns?

Comment: this lists contain same emount items
the name of clumn is clumn1,clumn2,clumn3...

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of the items is static, then you can create columns and name them, then iterate thru each of the `List<B>` items, and fill the current iterator index row with the appropriate columns by name or by column index.

But anyway I would say you do it the wrong way, since a list should be used for dynamic collections.
Use typed classes instead, then set the [AutoGenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) property.